# how to hide my source code so to not be copied

Tags: html, copy

I was recently informed by someone that my website was copied. When I looked at the linked that he gave me I so that the site was identic to mine except for the logo and text. Is there a way to hide my code? Or to make it impossible to right click on my page? I saw on some websites that if you go to http://example.com/images/ it will show access denied, not a list with all your images...How do they do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: I just posted an example. It is not a link. Some websites hide their images. On my website anyone can get them by adding /images...

Comment: @Claudiu In future, use the domain `example.com` to make clear that a link is supposed to be an example.  This domain is intended for this very purpose.  I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Don't do this!** It makes no sense to do this, since the user can disable the script,
and there are many tools like Firebug by which a user can see the code.

The best way to keep safe the store is installing a security camera while leaving the doors open.

You can simply disable the right click by following:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
  ...
</body>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript">
  document.onmousedown = disableclick;
  status = "Right Click Disabled";
  Function disableclick(e)
  {
    if(event.button == 2)
    {
      alert(status);
      return false; 
    }
  }
</script>
```

The code above is from this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11222/Disabling-the-right-click-on-web-page)

Comment: This will not prevent users to select View->Source from the main menu.

Comment: not good !!!!
if you do it ' the user can  press F12 and the developer console will show!!!!

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Annoying to normal users and doesn’t even accomplish its goal.

Answer (score 14):

You can do stuff which amounts to [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), but the only way to prevent your client-side web source from being copyable is to not push it down the wire, to not deliver it in the first place, shut down your website.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to hide one's code on the web. If you're sending information to the client-side, that information can be copied. That's not merely a fact of the web, that's a fact of information theory. The only option for cases like this is not prevention, but detection. [Many services exist to help in these situations](https://www.google.com/search?q=website%20copy%20detection%20services).

Depending on your web host, preventing the listing of files in an `images/` directory, for example, may be done by adding an `.htaccess` file with appropriate restrictions, or disabling directory listings from within your host's panel. The key words you need are "disabling directory listings". Talk to your webhost's support for more details, this is a very common request, so they likely already know exactly how to help you.

Note that this will only prevent the *listing* of images in a convenient form. If they are referenced on other pages on your site, they can still be easily downloaded.

Comment: You've given a nice answer to the question asked, but I want to know something else. If someone is copying my code, is there any method, that when the stealer opens the Firebug or Developer tools, he get a message something like that, "This website is protected by Copyscape Plagiarism Checker, so copying the source code and using it in your own website/webpage without the permission of Author will lead to the blocking of your domain and host, and you'll become the victim of Cyber Crimes Act".

Comment: Not universally. The best option for this sort of thing is usually a simple copyright message at the top of the file (as a comment) is a good option. Most Javascript optimizers have ways of ensuring copyright messages can remain intact, even when all other comments / whitespace have been stripped from the file.

One could print such a message on the javascript console when the page first loads, and that message would be visible to many debuggers when first opened, but as I said, this is not a universal solution, and outputting console messages is often frowned upon.

Comment: Palmser , I asked it becuase I saw it sometime ago when I was using facebook and when I opened the developer tools, it gave me a message in white font with red background, telling me that if someone have asked me to paste some (javascript) script in the console, it may lead to the leakage of my password to him. I wanted to use the same method to frighten the users which are novices but they steal content and the whole design. The problem with those novices is that they don't ever read the copyright and top comments etc. Anyway thank you for the nice and detailed reply.

Comment: Nonsense , Look at this , its code isnt hidden is it?
http://samy.pl/ Yeah its hidden even in view source!

Comment: @MEX It's ***obfuscated***, not *hidden*. It's not that there is no source code, it's just that the source is formatted in a way that appears strange to the naked eye.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, probably they have an access to your ftp account. If I were you I will change my ftp credentials.

And also, there are tools that would really copy all of the websites content, including its source codes. One notable is IDM or Internet Download Manager http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/ which has a Site Grabber feature.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the right click handler only stops honest people from getting the page source and not those using tools like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). You can obfuscate or minify your JavaScript (such as using [Google Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)) but, if the browser needs to get access to the code or content, so can someone who is malicious.

Answer (score 0):

just create an empty index.html page and upload to your images folder, that solves it, so whenever they use `/images`..

Answer (score 0):

imho, it is impossible. Even if you block right click, F12, Ctrl+C/V, or others shortcut to copy, you can still counter with disable JavaScript and copy the the page source.

Answer (score 0):

There is no full proof way.

But here is some strategy that can be employed to hide source code like using "**window.history.pushState()**"

Detail here - http://freelancer.usercv.com/blog/28/hide-website-source-code-in-view-source-using-stupid-one-line-chinese-hack-code