# Is it possible to hide code written in php in source code

Tags: php

below is my code where i am writing a code in php and calling it in body. When i run it and view source, the code gets visible. I have seen some site where nothing gets shown on source but a form appears on webpage. How can i do it too?

```
<?php
{   $avatar_form  = '<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myphoto.php">';
    $avatar_form .=   '<h4>Change your avatar</h4>';
    $avatar_form .=   '<input type="file" name="avatar" required>';
    $avatar_form .=   '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>';
    $avatar_form .= '</form>';
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Avatar</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><?php echo $avatar_form; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Shail

Comment: If you're seeing PHP code in the browser, your server's not set up right.  That, or your filename doesn't end in `.php`.

Comment: Presumably you have put it into an `.html` file. And your web server has no idea that it needs to process it as php

Comment: i think you want to hide your html source you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543704/how-to-hide-my-source-code-so-to-not-be-copied?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @zerkms/cHao - there are other php codes too on the file which has several logics and they are not visible, only this is becoming visible. My whole project is on php, i havent used html even on a single page.

Comment: @ShailendraHuntArya: Then figuring out what's different about that file would be a good start.

Comment: @cHao: i think my question description is little bit wrong, sorry for that. Whatever i have written before html tag is not visible in source. The form which i have written in php tags is getting visible in body section when we view the source code. I dont want anything becomes visible on source code that i have coded in php tags. Because if that is getting visible then there is no use of writing those in php. i only want that form to appear on webpage, not in body on source code. If you can suggest me something on this, then it will be of great help.

Comment: @ShailendraHuntArya:  In your particular case, there *isn't* any use writing it in PHP.  All PHP does, basically, is replace the `<?php ... ?>` sections with whatever output they generate.  The generated page's source code is still going to have whatever they echo out.  So unless that stuff is dynamically generated, it's better off just being in straight HTML.

Comment: For reference, there's not really such a thing as hiding HTML source.  The browser has to see the HTML before it knows what to show the user.  And telling it to betray the user and not show that HTML even when asked, is harder and more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write it in html? There should not be any code showing like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Avatar</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myphoto.php">
<h4>Change your avatar</h4>
<input type="file" name="avatar" required>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

just using php to echo html is sometimes not faster or useful then writing it directly in `.html` files.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is Output of the code,]
[image: And this is the page source showing at my side my browser..]
Check whether the file type is .php or .html?
if html, it will show the php code.
If so, save it as .php

Comment: it is php. i am not using html

Comment: Dear Shail, I copied you entire code and tested, its not showing any php code in view source, so can you please tell me more details so that I may help you out. Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to add a png file here

Comment: this whole is shown in body part on source code. i dont want this to appear to user.  <body>
<div><form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myphoto.php"><h4>Change your avatar</h4><input type="file" name="avatar" required><p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p></form></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Do you like to use right click disable jquery code in you programmed code? it will stop to click right.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").bind("contextmenu",function(){
       return false;
    }); 
});

Comment: not really, i dont have any problem if someone wants to see the normal coding

Comment: now review my answer again, to know how source code is being shown at my browser.

Comment: i understand, you are saying the above protion before the start of html section is not visible in source code. But my query is that how can i ide the form which is appearing on body. If that is appearing there then surely i need not to use php,  i can type the form there as in html