# how to hide my js files and js library from view-source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html

how to hide my js files and js library from view-source code

i found Javascript Obfuscator but this will be ok with my custom JS source code

what about the other files

i want to let those files not showd if others click view-source

```
    wp_register_script('dataTables.min.js', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', array('jquery'), true);

    wp_register_script('customjs.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customjs.js', array('jquery'), true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs.js');
    wp_enqueue_style('dataTables.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('buttons.dataTables.min.css');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543704/how-to-hide-my-source-code-so-to-not-be-copied). However, you can compile all your javascript or CSS or even the HTML code by using [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/). Using these can optimize your page, can uglify scripts. With that, they can't easily read your source code but they can still copy it but still, It makes no sense to do this, since the user can disable javascript in the browser and there are a lot of tools that users can use to see the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You cant really hide your js files and libraries when you on view-source mode. However, you can minify and uglify them to make them hard to read.

Comment: is there are any way to use .htaccess to prevent view-source from public view or changing the name of library